# How save state of GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps, savestate

I want to know how to save the state of a GoogleMap

I have a fragment with GoogleMap, and when i rotate the screen this map is reload again.
For example, if you open the app of Google Maps, load the map, and when you rotate the screen, map not reload. But in my map is reload (pixelated to no-pixelated).

I know the way to save the state of `Camera` and restore this, but it isn't the problem.

How can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using fragment, there are few other options you can try in the java code apart from setting the setting "orientation|screensize" in XML.

- Extend the Fragment class and declare references to your stateful objects.
- Call setRetainInstance(boolean) when the fragment is created.
- Add the fragment to your activity
- Use FragmentManager to retrieve the fragment when the activity is restarted.

Then use FragmentManager to add the fragment to the activity. You can obtain the data object from the fragment when the activity starts again during runtime configuration changes.

Another option is to fix the orientation either to landscape or portrait, which will fix the screen.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

// Checks the orientation of the screen
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

For more details please refer to this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject).

Hope this would help!!

Comment: But the data that i don't want lost is in a fragment, a fragment with a GoogleMap. I will try to adapt this solution to a fragment. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

When you rotate the screen your view is trying to reload its data. You can check if your map is null then setup your map. something like this:

```
private void setupMapIfNeeded() {
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    if (mMap == null) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need the rotation.

Comment: Sorry, I had not understood your solution. This works in `Activity`, but not in `Fragment`

Comment: add this line into your activity tag in your manifest. it works in all fragments assosiated to that activity @hlastras

Comment: and also it won't lock the rotation and you can have rotation as well.

Comment: Thanks @Milad, but I need the automatic rotation in that activity, but not in fragment. The activity have more fragment. I have to leave like this.